# Не подключается slick slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap, slick.js

Не работает slick slider div'ы просто стают в столбик, вот мои подключённые файлы

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css">
<!-- Your custom styles (optional) -->

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/compiled-4.7.4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
```

Участок кода который должен быть слайдером:

```
<div class="your-class">
  <div>your content</div>
  <div>your content</div>
  <div>your content</div>
</div>
```

Скрипты:

```
<!-- SCRIPTS -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#carousel-example-1z").carousel({
       interval : false;
});
$("#carousel-example-2z").carousel({
   interval : false;
});
$('.your-class').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000,
});
});
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mdb.js"></script>
```

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Поменяйте порядок подключения jquery и slick. И вызов $('.your-class').slick() должен идти, естественно, после подключенных скриптов

Comment: @humster_spb всё сделал, ничего не изменилось, что может значить ошибка err_aborted

Comment: а сейчас какие ошибки в консоли?

Comment: @humster_spb добавил скриншот

Comment: Ну, очевидно, проблема в swiper. Он Вам вообще зачем, если Вы используете slick?

Comment: Битая ссылка: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.x.x/js/swiper.js - из-за неё все проблемы

Comment: @humster_spb спасибо огромное, пишите ответ, поставлю галочку

Comment: В принципе Вам вот здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/964123/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-swipe-slider-%D0%B8-slick-slider-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-neterr-aborted-404 дали такой же ответ как и я - можете там поставить галочку :) А этот вопрос удалить. Дублировать одни и те же вопросы - плохая практика

Comment: @humster_spb спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Информации недостаточно, чтобы Вам помочь.
Пара моментов:

- у Вас все CSS и JS грузятся локально из сайта, а slick - из CDN. Попробуйте и его загрузить локально, как всех;
- у Вас 3 элемента, и слайдер вы инициализируете, чтобы показывать 3 элемента. Зачем он тогда нужен? Или элементов больше?

Вот пример с использованием Вашего кода. У Вас получается что-то другое?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.your-class').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000,
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="your-class">
  <div>your content 1</div>
  <div>your content 2</div>
  <div>your content 3</div>
  <div>your content 4</div>
  <div>your content 5</div>
  <div>your content 6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Элементов больше, пробовал подключать локально, не помогает, есть ещё какие-то варианты?Также у меня подключены все стили для mdbootstrap

Comment: У меня элементы просто становятся в столбик, какую информации ещё нужно сообщить?

Comment: Прикрепил скриншот консоли