# Не подключается swipe-slider и slick-slider ошибка net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js, swipe

Не подключаются слайдеры

Стили

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.x.x/css/swiper.min.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Скрипты

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.your-class').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000,
});
});
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.x.x/js/swiper.js"></script>
    <script>
   var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
     slidesPerView: 3,
     spaceBetween: 30,
     pagination: {
       el: '.swiper-pagination',
       clickable: true,
     },
   });
 </script>
```

[image: Скриншот консоли]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас не подключен Swiper Slider т.к. Вы не указали версию.
Так же проверьте подключен ли jQuery.

В документации к Swiper есть такая строка

> Don't forget to change 4.x.x to actual Swiper version

Видимо вы не обратили внимание на это.

Вставьте этот код и будет работать.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/css/swiper.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
```

Так же у Вас не выбран контейнер для инициализации Slick Slider.

Замените `$('.your-class')`
на Ваш div с классом, где хотите видеть Slick Slider.

А вот тут можете посмотреть демки для Swiper Slider [ссылка](https://idangero.us/swiper/demos/)

По ссылке `Source Code` найдете пример использования слайдера.